Replacing caulk between countertop sections
New house and I noticed some cracking in the bonding agent between the countertop sections and wanted to identify what it was before replacing it.
It's around the area where the stove is. On the front it looks good and like this

As you can see, it has a slight sheen to it which makes me think it might be some sort of almond-colored caulk or something. On the backside it's cracked and looks like this:

Is this in fact caulk? Just wanted to double check before replacing. Not sure if an remodeler would use something else (e.g., some sort of epoxy) between horizontal sections of countertop or not.

It's probably grout in a tube.

Joints between sections of (stone or faux-stone, evidently) countertop are commonly an epoxy, while joints between different materials (stone to stainless steel and stone to tile) would more typically be caulk.

Yeah, looks to me like the countertop has settled.  Well, more likely the cabinets below—or the floor—have settled.

Thanks. Do you have any idea what sort of epoxy might be used here? Something I can get at a big box store?

Well, it should be a specialized product which is usually limited in distribution to countertop installers. Which is to say it's unlikely to be sold at a big box. Since your stone appears to be granite, look for a "Granite seam epoxy" which may require you to seek other sources of supply.
